# Data is not coming if i use async in vue js 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I am implementing Quiz App but here I am facing an issue if I put static data in array the questions are coming.

Data is not coming if i use async in Vue JS 3

But If I Call data from the API the questions are not showing.

when I console the questions are showing in console and not showing in the front end.

For ref please find the attached code and image.

Home.vue (please see fetchQuestionsFromServer function)

```html
     <template>
      <main class="flex h-screen items-center justify-center bg-gray-100">
        <!-- quiz container -->
          <QuizComplatePage v-if="endofQuiz" />
        <div
          class="overflow-hidden bg-white flex-none container relative shadow-lg rounded-lg px-12 py-6"
        >
          <img
            src="@/assets/images/abstract.svg"
            alt=""
            class="absolute -top-10 left-0 object-none"
          />
    
          <!-- contents -->
          <div class="relative z-20">
            <!-- score container -->
            <div class="text-right text-gray-800">
              <p class="text-sm leading-3">Score</p>
              <p class="font-bold">{{score}}</p>
            </div>
    
            <!-- timer container -->
            <div class="bg-white shadow-lg p-1 rounded-full w-full h-5 mt-4">
              <div class="bg-blue-700 rounded-full w-11/12 h-full" 
              :style= "`width: ${timer}%`"
              ></div>
            </div>
    
            <!-- question container -->
            <div
              class="rounded-lg bg-gray-100 p-2 neumorph-1 text-center font-bold text-gray-800 mt-8"
            >
              <div class="bg-white p-5">
               {{currentQuestion.question}}
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <!-- options container -->
    
            <div class="mt-8">
              <!-- option container -->
              <div v-for="(choice,item) in currentQuestion.choices" :key="item">
                <div
                class="neumorph-1 option-default bg-gray-100 p-2 rounded-lg mb-3 relative"
                :ref="optionchosen"
                @click="onOptionClick(choice,item)"
              >
                <div
                  class="bg-blue-700 p-1 transform rotate-45 rounded-md h-10 w-10 text-white font-bold absolute right-0 top-0 shadow-md"
                >
                  <p class="transform -rotate-45">+10</p>
                </div>
                <div class="rounded-lg font-bold flex p-2">
                  <!-- option ID -->
                  <div class="p-3 rounded-lg">{{item}}</div>
    
                  <!-- option name -->
                  <div class="flex items-center pl-6">{{choice}}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <!-- option container -->
            </div>
    
            <!-- progress indicator container -->
            <div class="mt-8 text-center">
              <div class="h-1 w-12 bg-gray-800 rounded-full mx-auto"></div>
              <p class="font-bold text-gray-800">{{questionCounter}}/{{questions.length}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </template>
    <script>
    import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
    import QuizComplatePage from './QuizCompleteOverlay.vue'
    export default{
      components: {
    QuizComplatePage
      },
      setup(){
        //data
        let canClick = true
        let score = ref(0)
        let timer = ref(100)
        let endofQuiz = ref(false)
        let questionCounter = ref(0)
        const currentQuestion = ref({
          question: '',
          answer: 1,
          choices: [],
        });
        const questions = []
    
    const loadQuestion = () =>{
      canClick = true
      timer.value=100
      //Check question array had questions or not
      if(questions.length > questionCounter.value){
         currentQuestion.value = questions[questionCounter.value]
         console.log('Current Question is : ', currentQuestion.value);
         questionCounter.value++
      }else{
        endofQuiz.value = true
        console.log('Out of Questions');
      }
     
    }
    
    
    //methods
    let itemsRef = []
    const optionchosen = (element) =>{
      if(element){
    itemsRef.push(element)
      }
    }
    
    const clearSelected = (divselected) =>{
      setTimeout(()=>{
      divselected.classList.remove('option-correct')
      divselected.classList.remove('option-wrong')
      divselected.classList.add('option-default')
      loadQuestion()
      },1000)
      
    }
    
    const onOptionClick = (choice,item) =>{
      if(canClick)
      {
        const divContainer = itemsRef[item]
      const optionId = item+1
      if(currentQuestion.value.answer ===optionId){
        console.log('You are Correct');
        score.value += 10
        divContainer.classList.add('option-correct')
        divContainer.classList.remove('option-default')
      }else{
        console.log('You are Wrong');
        divContainer.classList.add('option-wrong')
        divContainer.classList.remove('option-default')
      }
      timer.value=100
      canClick=false
      //to go next question
      clearSelected(divContainer)
      console.log(choice,item);
      }else{
        console.log('Cant Select Option');
      }
    }
    
    const countDownTimer = () =>{
    let interval= setInterval(()=>{
      if(timer.value>0){
        timer.value--
      }else{
        console.log('Time is over');
        clearInterval(interval)
      }
    
     },150)
    }
    
    const fetchQuestionsFromServer = async function(){
       fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=18&type=multiple')
      .then((res) =>{
        return res.json()
      })
      .then((data) =>{
        const newQuestions = data.results.map((serverQuestion) =>{
          const arrangedQuestion = {
            question: serverQuestion.question,
            choices: '',
            answer: ''
            
          }
          const choices = serverQuestion.incorrect_answers
          arrangedQuestion.answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1)
          choices.splice(arrangedQuestion.answer-1 , 0 , serverQuestion.correct_answer)
          arrangedQuestion.choices = choices
          return arrangedQuestion
        })
        console.log('new formated questions' , newQuestions);
        questions.value = newQuestions
        loadQuestion()
        countDownTimer()
        console.log('questions: =>' , questions.value);
        
      })
    }
    
    
    //lifecycle hooks
    onMounted(() =>{
      fetchQuestionsFromServer()
    })
    
    
      //return
        return {
          timer,
          currentQuestion, 
          questions, 
          score,
          questionCounter, 
          loadQuestion,
          onOptionClick,
          optionchosen,
          endofQuiz,
          }
      }
    }
    </script>
    
     <style scoped>
    .neumorph-1 {
      box-shadow: 6px 6px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09), -6px -6px 18px #ffffff;
    }
    .container {
      max-width: 400px;
      border-radius: 25px;
    }
    </style>
```

QuizComplatePage.vue

```html
    <template>
      
      <div class="w-screen h-screen absolute z-30 bg-white bg-opacity-30 flex justify-center items-center">
    
        <div class="bg-green-700 p-4 text-center text-white">
            <p class="font-bold text-2xl">All DOne!</p>
            <p class="my-4 font-bold text-3xl">100% Score</p>
    
            <!-- Buttons -->
            <div class="flex justify-center">
                <div class="rounded-full py-1 w-28 border cursor-pointer hover:text-black hover:bg-white">Done</div>
                <div class="rounded-full py-1 w-28 border cursor-pointer hover:text-black hover:bg-white">Retry</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
        name: 'QuizComplatePage'
    
    }
    </script>
    
    <style>
    
    </style>
```

Image.

[image: Please find the image also]

Comment: Your `questions` variable not reactive, use `ref([])` instead of `[]`. Read it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76032628/15167500

Answer (score 0):

You are not using value when you need to:

For instance look in this function

questions.length should be questions.value.length

Also currentQuestion.value = questions.value[questionCounter.value]

Start by fixing that.

Everything that is a ref in your setup needs to be accessed by .value in anything inside your setup. Outside your setup it will have this and can be treated normally. Mixing these two up is the most common error.

```
const loadQuestion = () =>{
      canClick = true
      timer.value=100
      //Check question array had questions or not
      if(questions.value.length > questionCounter.value){
         currentQuestion.value = questions.value[questionCounter.value]
         console.log('Current Question is : ', currentQuestion.value);
         questionCounter.value++
      }else{
        endofQuiz.value = true
        console.log('Out of Questions');
      }
     
    }
```

Comment: if i pass questions.value.length i am getting this error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'question')

Comment: You still have a questions without value in that function

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution

let questions = []

questions = newQuestions

Now I am able to load questions.